# I am writing one soap web service to download files from my local, but below errors are coming

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Below exception is coming

> Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl Message:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl

---

**Code**

```
package com.hoja; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FilePermission; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response; import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder; 
public class BhaiHoja { 
  @Produces("application/pdf") 
  public Response getFile(String policyNo, String docId){
    String constFilePath = "C:/Users/Anushree/Desktop/Webservice/"; 
    String flow = (constFilePath + "/" + policyNo + "/" + docId +".pdf"); 
    File fileNew = new File(constFilePath + "/" + policyNo + "/" + docId +".pdf"); 
    File FilePath = new File("C:/Users/Anushree/Desktop/Webservice/"); FilePermission permission = new FilePermission(flow, "read");  ResponseBuilder 
    res = Response.ok((Object)fileNew ); 
    res.header("content-disposition","attachment;filename=fileNew");  
    return res.build(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Jersey is not on your classpath.

Comment: i have given but still its coming

Comment: Do you use gradle or Maven?